# Run Jasmine tests on a view in a MVC project.

Tags: testing, model-view-controller, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to set up testing with Chutzpah in Visual Studio 2013 and Jasmine tests. I can use fixtures to load in html files, and as far as I understand these will be put inside a default harness file's body.

Instead, I'd like to create tests for the actual production code and basically run some tests on the masterpage we use for all the views to check that everything has loaded correctly, looks the way it should etc.

Is there any obvious way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for more functional style testing than unit testing. If you still want to use the PhantomJS headless browser for this I would recommend using [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) which provides an easy way to automate webpage navigation and assertion.

For example, hear is an excerpt from [their documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#browser-tests) on testing:

```
casper.test.begin('Google search retrieves 10 or more results', 5, function suite(test) {
    casper.start("http://www.google.fr/", function() {
        test.assertTitle("Google", "google homepage title is the one expected");
        test.assertExists('form[action="/search"]', "main form is found");
        this.fill('form[action="/search"]', {
            q: "casperjs"
        }, true);
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTitle("casperjs - Recherche Google", "google title is ok");
        test.assertUrlMatch(/q=casperjs/, "search term has been submitted");
        test.assertEval(function() {
            return __utils__.findAll("h3.r").length >= 10;
        }, "google search for \"casperjs\" retrieves 10 or more results");
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion myself and were planning to look into Selenium and NUnit but CasperJS looks perfect for my needs :) Thanks for the tip! :)